# Issue with custom time format method

Tags: java, java-time

I've build a getTimeFormatted method so that I can format the time based on my requirements. However, I can only find examples where the method formats one time I pass to it. I need my method to be able to format whatever time I pass to it. If my time format requirements change I want to update it in one place. Any suggestions?

```java
public class TimeTest { 
    static LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.now();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTimeFormatted());
    }
    
    public static String getTimeFormatted() {
        DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return tf.format(startTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods can have parameters. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: In this case should they be object or string parameters? What does that look like in the custom method?  Because date time have their own classes and methods, it’s challenging to find useful examples that are not just how to use existing date and time classes or methods in the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the time as a parameter to your method to format any time value you like. e.g.:

```java
public class TimeTest { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.now().plusHours(5);
        System.out.println(getTimeFormatted(time1));
        System.out.println(getTimeFormatted(time2));
    }
    
    public static String getTimeFormatted(LocalTime time) {
        DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return tf.format(time);
    }
}
```